# Where do the two $a!$s come from?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

I have
\begin{align*}
  (2a)!
  &\equiv a! (-a) \dotsm (-3)(-2)(-1)  \pmod p\\ 
  & \equiv (-1)^a a!a!\pmod p\\
  &\equiv (-1)^a a!^2\pmod p.
\end{align*}
The $(-1)$ is just to get the parity right and can be neglected in solving my problem, which is: from where do the two $a!$s come from? I know where one comes from but not the other. If it is from $(2a)!$ how so? I tried to send a scanned page from "An adventurers guide to Number Theory" page 172 but could not do it using your format.

Comment: Is your question the first equal sign or the second?

Comment: $$(2\cdot1)! \not\equiv 1!\ (-1)\pmod2$$Are there any other conditions?

Comment: In that book p=2a+1.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an extra condition $p=2a+1$ like what @Max said above, then

$$\begin{align*}
2a =& p-1, &2a \equiv& -1\pmod{p}\\
2a-1=&p-2, &2a-1 \equiv& -2 \pmod{p}\\
\vdots&&\vdots&\\
2a-(a-1)=&p-a, &a+1 \equiv& -a \pmod{p}
\end{align*}$$

So
$$\begin{align*}
(2a)! \equiv& a!\ (a+1)\cdots(2a-1)(2a) &\pmod{p}\\
\equiv& a!\ (-a)\cdots(-2)(-1)&\pmod{p}\\
\equiv& a!\ (-1)a\cdots(-1)2(-1)1&\pmod{p}\\
\equiv& a!\ \left[(-1)^aa!\right]&\pmod{p}
\end{align*}$$